# Deploy an interactive ipywidget jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab, ipywidgets, bqplot

I have created a plot (with bqplot) with some sliders with (ipywidgets) in a jupyter notebook using Jupyter Lab and now I would like to send this notebook to anyone and have the widget work, that is, when I'm running the code, everything works fine, but as soon as I shut down the kernel and load the notebook again I have to run all the code again to have the widget working again. How can I do this?

Comment: I don't think this is possible in the current form. bqplot and ipywidgets rely on the python kernel to function, so shutting down will inevitably cause them to close / stop working.

There are options for distributing webpages with widgets built in, voila might work for you (https://github.com/voila-dashboards/voila).